# object Object in custom Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, sharetribe

I'm managing the page hengerdeling.no, and suddenly a few days ago "[object Object]" started to show on the single markers. Has Google made any update that might have caused this? Anyone with a suggestion on how to remove this text? The functionality of the map seems to be just fine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: update your question and show your related code

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I suspect it's due to Google's latest API update Oct 31 ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference)). Will do some code modifications to see if it's compatible with previous releases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it *was* because of the latest release. Worked well using the 3.25 release of the Google Maps API. Haven't had time to dive into the code to see exactly what caused it though...